# Doctrine crud generation in vendor

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, crud

I am trying to use the Symfony2 `app/console` command tool to generate a **CRUD** with the doctrine2 command. (`app/console doctrine:generate:crud`)

**Here is the problem :**
I want to generate it in the **vendors** (Yes, we develop some bundles directly in vendors in our startup).
When I do the command and give the **Entity Shortcut Name**, It returns me an error :

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
  Unknown Entity namespace alias 'ExampleTemplateBundle'.
```

(Yes the entity exists and the Entity Shortcut name is good)

Is there a way to generate CRUD in the vendors with Symfony2 and Doctrine2?

Comment: Is ExampleTemplateBundle registered within AppKernel? Why would you develop in vendors dir? It should be ignored by version control.

Comment: Yes it is registered. We are developing in vendors because every vendors has its own git repo and it is easier to manage.

Comment: I think one way is to create your own command extending the doc:gen:crud command...

Comment: Sounds to me the bundle has some config error. Perhaps it is not loading it's config? or extension class? A small typo in a dir-name might cause some files to be in an unexpected location and failing to load. I doubt using the vendor-dir is a problem. It is unconventional, but should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

I have tracked down the error and corrected the issue. It resided in the **doctrine/doctrine-bundle** (**v1.2.0** for me).

The thing that made fails the proccess was located in the file `DoctrineBundle/Mapping/MetadataFactory.php`

**EDIT :** For people using the doctrine-bundle v1.3.0 and over, the file has changed name. It is now `DisconnectedMetadataFactory.php`

The failing code was the following :

```
    private function getBasePathForClass($name, $namespace, $path)
{
    $namespace = str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace);
    $search = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
    $destination = str_replace('/'.$namespace, '', $search, $c);
    if ($c != 1) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Can\'t find base path for "%s" (path: "%s", destination: "%s").', $name, $path, $destination));
    }
    return $destination;
}
```

So what I did is, I forked the repo, replaced the code by this :

```
private function getBasePathForClass($name, $namespace, $path)
{
    $namespace = str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace);
    $search = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
    $destination = str_replace('/' . $namespace, '', $search);

    return $destination;
}
```

And updated my composer.json to use my forked version of the **doctrine/doctrine-bundle**.
Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a vendor.
Try inherit it and create a crud for your own entity.

Comment: If you are the "owner" of the repo loaded in the vendor-dir, and you loaded a dev-version (which is just a branch), you can modify the code right in the vendor dir. It's just a bit of a hassle when committing. (you need to commit and push the code in your vendor-dir separately). Works wonders when fixing problems or adding features to library-code or generic bundles.